# Laravel 5: Fetch ajax data in route and pass to controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and want to make ajax call to a controller with some data:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "/getOrgById",
    data : JSON.stringify({id:1})
})
```

The `routes.php` has:

```
Route::get('/getOrgById', 'HomeController@getOrgById');
```

`HomeController.php`:

```
public function getOrgById($data) {
   //code here fails with message 'Missing argument 1 for HomeController::getOrgById()
}
```

How can I pass the data from ajax to route and then to controller?

Comment: It seems like you're approaching some CRUD-like structure; I'd suggest you create a separate controller and register it with `Route::resource('organizations', 'OrganizationsController')` and add a `show($id)` method to that. That'll allow you to do `/organizations/1` out of the box. If you insist on getting the data by passing a query parameter, just remove the `$data` from the `getOrgById` method and access the id with `Request::get('id')`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the below example is what you're looking for

Route

```
Route::post('/getOrgById', 'HomeController@getOrgById');
```

Controller

```
public function getOrgById(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->input('id');
}
```

JS

```
var myJsonData = {id: 1}
$.post('/getOrgById', myJsonData, function(response) {
    //handle response
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really look into resourceful controller actions. If you are wanting to fetch an organisation by its ID then you have an organisaiton entity, so create a corresponding organisation controller. This controller can then have a method to *show* an organisation by on its primary key value:

```
class OrganisationController
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        return Organisation::findOrFail($id);
    }
}
```

The route for this would look like:

```
Route::get('/organisations/{id}', 'OrganisationController@show');
```

You can then request this route via AJAX like so:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/organisations/' + id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Input` to get your variable

```
public function getOrgById() {
     $data = \Input::get('data')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define paramers in your route:

```
Route::get('/getOrgById/{id}', 'HomeController@getOrgById');
```

And call it through:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/getOrgById" + id
})
```

Comment: You are right in the example where I have only one variable. But what if I want to pass a complex json?

Comment: You can use `Input::get()` to retrieve your datas

Comment: I think you forgot a "/" after getOrgById.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right, but when using `$data` in your function declaration you're actually requiring a Query String variable, rather than a form request.

You have to add your Form Request in your Controller method, like so:

```
public function getOrgById(Request $request){
    // do something here...
    return response()->json(array('foo' => 'bar'));
}
```

Comment: As a demostration of the feature, nothing else. I also return 422 when form validation fails, using JSON.

Comment: A 422 should _only_ be returned for validation failures. Given the copy-paste nature of Stack Overflow, you should _not_ include setting something like a 422 status code on a successful request as a “demonstration” of the feature. It’s incorrect, and also had nothing to do with the question asked by the OP.

Comment: It's a technicallity we can all live with. In the end, I would be helping OP by letting him now he/she has multiple choices.

Comment: There are “choices” _everywhere_ in code, but demonstrating status codes (which the question has nothing to do with) and demonstrating the _wrong_ one on this occasion, is reckless and will do more harm than good with the “copy-paste” nature of Stack Overflow answers. Please be more careful in future. I’ve had to edit your answer because of this.

Answer (score 0):

ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:'/getOrgById',
    data:{
        id:1
    },
    success:function(res){
    }

});
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/getOrgById', 'HomeController@getOrgById');
```

HomeController.php:

```
public function getOrgById(Request $request) {
    dd($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

**HTML Form**

```
<div id="loadingResponse"></div>
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'test/submit', 'id'=>'submitForm','method'=>'POST'))!!}
    {{Form::token()}}
    <input type="text" name="data"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-info">Send Data</button>
{{Form::close()}}
```

**JS Ajax**

```
$("#submitForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url         : 'test/submit',
        data        : new FormData($("#submitForm")[0]),
        dataType    : 'JSON',
        type        : 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loadingResponse").html("<img src='{{asset('img/loading.gif')}}' />");
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('Error '+xhr.status+' | '+thrownError);
        },
    });
});
```

**PHP Route**

```
...
Route::post("test/submit","TestController@submit");
...
```

**PHP Controller**

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        response()->json(['msj' => $request->input('data')]);
    }
    ...
}
```